# How to check dropDown status (shown or hidden) in autoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

How to check dropdown status (shown or hidden) in `AutoCompleteTextView` in Android?

Answer (score 12):

You can use [**`isPopupShowing()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#isPopupShowing()) method.

> Indicates whether the popup menu is showing.
>       Returns
>       true if the popup menu is showing, false otherwise

**Finally**

```
if(YourAutoCompleteTextViewObject.isPopupShowing()){
// Your code
}else{
// Your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(autoCompleteTextView.isPopupShowing()){
......
}else{

...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `isPopupShowing` for this.
Here you can find many other interesting things: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html